# Razor Url.Action and mvc routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Given this:
in index.cshtml:

```
 a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Request")">Create Request</a>
```

global.asax:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                "Request",
                "request/{action}",
                new {controller="Request",action="Create" }
                );
```

It redirects to this url: http://localhost:16997/request. 
How would I make it go to http://localhost:16997/request/create ? If I just type the 'create' in the url, it displays the Content of the create method appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the action default value in your route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Request", 
    "request/{action}", 
    new { controller = "Request" } 
);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it work if he just put his route above this one in the Global.asax? As routing will match the first one it can.

Comment: It will work if he completely removes his custom route as it is not needed. The default route already handles this. And its default action is Index.

Comment: updated the route, and it redirects properly: http://localhost:16997/request/create but the browser only displays 'Undefined'. All the method does is 'return Content("inside request controller create method");

Comment: If I put http://localhost:16997/request/create/whatever in the browser, it displays the Content of the create method. If I manually enter http://localhost:16997/request/create/ in a browser, it displays the Content - but if I redirect using Url.Action, it returns Undefined. ? I'm using vs2010/mvc3/safari in ipad mode.